# Postgres `\d` shows table but `\d table` does not exist?

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr

I query Postgres with `\d` and get a list of tables including table `foo`.

```
 Schema | Name | Type  |  Owner
--------+------+-------+----------
 public | foo  | table | postgres
```

I then query `\d foo`, and get told: `Did not find any relation named "foo".`

When I then try `DROP TABLE foo`, `ERROR: table "foo" does not exist.`

Adding the name of the scheme does not change the response.

What could be the cause?

The error came about when using [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) with and without `-overwrite -lco OVERWRITE=YES`, and both combinations, which some say has issues, although I have used the tool for hours a day for months without seeing the problem.

Comment: Could be the search_path, try using the schema: DROP TABLE public.foo;

Comment: @FrankHeikens - thanks, but no change.

Comment: Trailing space in table-name? Try get length.

Comment: DROP DATABASE will also destroy this table...

Comment: Try `SELECT oid::regclass FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE '%foo%';` to see the (possibly quoted) name. That is, unless there are weird characters in the middle of the name.

Comment: @FrankHeikens - "When I then try DROP TABLE foo, ERROR: table "foo" does not exist"

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - Thank you! There *was* a space after the table name! When kometen suggested that, I checked the wrong line of my code. Checking the actual scheme solved the problem. Thanks again. Please post as an answer so I can give you proper credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very likely hidden or invisible characters in the table name. Provided that `foo` is a part of the table name, you can list all such table names with

```
SELECT oid::regclass
FROM pg_class
WHERE relname LIKE '%foo%';
```

If there are any spaces or weird characters in the name, it will be output with double quotes, like

```
"foo "
```

You can just copy and paste that quoted name into your `DROP TABLE` statement.